# "X is inequitable because Y is disproportionate to Z." Is there a better way to put this?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests, sentence

> While a full Major League Baseball season is 162 games, the first
>   round of the playoffs is only a 5 game series. ***I feel that this
>   system is inequitable because the length of the opening playoff
>   series is disproportionate to that of the MLB season.***

The bolded sentence above *feels* wrong:

- Would "this discrepancy" work better than "this system" in the above sentence?
- Is there a clearer/stronger way to express the opinion that "X is inequitable because Y is disproportionate to Z?"

Comment: Definitely looks wrong to me but is that just because of a rogue "opening"?

Comment: Ok, it no longer feels wrong after your edit. But now, I'm not really sure what it's trying to say. Perhaps that's partly because I don't know much about Baseball. Are you saying that you think the first playoff series should be more than 5 games? If so, why? As I understand it, the playoff series would be between 2 teams, while the league season will have involved a lot more teams (all playing each other, home and away?). So it's not clear to me in what sense it's appropriate to compare the 5 with the 162.

Comment: @Rupe thanks. "Are you saying that you think the first playoff series should be more than 5 games? If so, why?" Yes, *because* the season is so long in comparison to the first round of the playoffs. It seems unfair that a team could be eliminated after losing a mere 3 games given the 162 games are needed to get to that point.

Comment: That's interesting. Here in the UK I think people would be more inclined to ask "why bother to have a series of 5 matches to determine which of 2 teams should prevail?". We have something similar in football, where at the end of the season there are playoffs between 4 teams (i.e. two semis and a final) to determine which one out of 4 teams gets promoted from one division to the next. The semis are played over 2 legs (home and away) and then the final is a single match at a neutral venue (this is at the end of a season of 46 matches).

Comment: Also, I can't see how it's "inequitable". Surely, whatever one thinks about the number of matches, both teams in the playoff series are in the same situation? Sorry, not sure if I'm getting off-topic here! With regard to the bullet-pointed question, I'm fine with the construction of the sentence "X is inequitable because Y is disproportionate to Z". It's just that in the specific case I'm not convinced that either "inequitable" or "disproportionate" is the right word to be using.

Comment: @Rupe - Baseball has multiple matches because it better tests the depth of a team.  One pitcher can dominate a game, but he can't play each day.  It is more like cricket than football.

Comment: Actually in the 19th century they had a year when they played best of 15 as the "World Series"..and they hadn't invented the "stop when one team wins the 50% + 1 game" thing yet.  It did not go over well.

Comment: @Oldcat Thanks for the clarifications, the cricket analogy helped for sure!

Comment: How many times would teams have played each other during the 162 match season? I guess where I'm coming from here is that for me, njboot's use of "disproportionate" begs the question, "in proportion to what?". Is it being said that (only) 5 matches is disproportionate with regard to the number of teams involved, the importance of the match, or what? Sure, 5/162 is a small fraction but it's not obvious from those numbers that it's "disproportionate" in any way that matters, because there's a big difference between a league of many teams and a playoff between two teams.

Comment: @Rupe the *length* (5 gms) is disproportionate to that of regular season (162 gms). I used disproportionate b/c I feel it implies the length of the former is *unreasonably small* compared to that of the latter.

Comment: @Rupe - MLB has 2 leagues and three divisions per league. You play 19 games × 4 opponents in own division (76 games), 6 or 7 games × 10 opponents in other divisions within league (66 games), 20 inter-league games.  Normally you play three or four games in a row vs a team during the year, some at your park and later some at his.

Comment: @Oldcat So, to me it makes more sense to compare the number of games in a playoff series with the number of times a pair of teams play each other during the season. You want it to be more, because you want it to be a better individual test between the 2 teams. During the season the test doesn't have to be so good because its variability is hopefully evened out over the course of the season (and that's where the number of matches played in a season comes into things because the more matches, the better the test variability is evened out).

Comment: Or another way to look at it is that a playoff series should be comparable to a regular season series at each team's park, which on average would be 6 games.  The opening series is 5 games, the others 7.  This fits in well with teams having 4 or 5 starting pitchers rotating during the year.

Answer (score 1):

I think the original sentence is slightly better. Using *discrepancy* makes it seem redundant or circular: being disproportionate is similar to having a discrepancy. It would also require the reader to recognize that the first sentence describes a discrepancy in the first place; this isn't obvious, since it's common for post-season playoffs and finals to be shorter than regular season play, because fewer teams are involved. So the reader's reaction might be "What discrepancy? It's apples and oranges." So prior to referring to *this discrepancy*, you should make it clear that you think this constitutes a discrepancy. But this is effectively what you're doing in the original sentence by saying that the system is inequitable because of the difference in lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The bolded sentence sounds fine/clear enough to me. Either `system` or `discrepancy` would work as the subject.